# Android Realm: Retrieve collection ids from realm Object

Tags: android, realm

I have saved my User to the realm. When I query the user I get this object:

```
User{id=0, hairColor=Red, favoriteSongs=FavoriteSong@[16,17]}
```

When I want the list of favorite songs, realm makes it easy to get a list back:

```
mUser.getFavoriteSongs();
```

But I'd like to get an array of the user's favoriteSong ids. This will make it easy to pass in a bundle as an **int[]**.

Is this possible in Realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose you two options:

1. Create a helper responsible of iterate the list of Songs and return a list of ids.

   ```
   class SongHelper {

       public static List<Integer> getSongIds(List<Song> songs) {
           List<Integer> songIds = new ArrayList<>();
           for( Song song : songs )
              songIds.add( song.getId() );

           return songIds;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Override the getFavoriteSongs method and make it return `List<Integer>` instead of `List<Song>` or create an additional method for this in the User.

Option 1 is more elegant. You should always keep your model classes as clean as possible. In other words, just declare attributes, getter and setters without business logic.

Comment: I'm aware of how to do this with a loop, I just need to know if Realm provides a helper method to achieve this. Would rather not write out 40+ individual helper methods if possible.

Comment: Ok! That's not possible using realm but you can use RxJava to iterate in a more fluent way. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#rxjava . That's all I can say!